# How to replace a meta tag in Yii?

Tags: yii, meta-tags

I know that I can register a new meta tag in Yii and I know how to do it, but I need to

replace the default tag that I have set, because when I am on a article, I want to insert the

short description of the article in the meta tag;

How can I manage the meta tags?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're on the latest version you can give the metatag an id.

```
->registerMetaTag('example', 'description', null, array(), 'mytagid');
```

Calling registerMetaTag again with the same id will overwrite it.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerMetaTag-detail

Comment: I already have a description meta tag; i want to replace the content of the description;

Comment: My answer above will do that. Using an id will allow you to overwrite any existing description.

Comment: Alex, thank for the help; we solved this issue; it turns our that Yii doesn't manage the static mate tags; it manages only the tags that you generate using its internal engine;

Answer (score 7):

You can set Meta tag per page using:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag("This is my meta description", 'description');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag("These, are, my, keywords", 'keywords');
```

This can be set in the Controller or the view, and obviously depending on how you are querying your articles, you can make the content part dynamic like so (assuming `$model` is your selected article and `meta_description` is your model attribute storing the meta description):

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag($model->meta_description, 'description');
```

Documentation on the [Yii site can be found here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#metaTags-detail)

Comment: I already have a description meta tag; i want to replace the content of the description;

Comment: What do you mean by replace? Replace once the page has loaded? I see you have accepted an answer, just asking out of curiosity :)

Comment: yes, replace the content of a default meta tag with new content

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

**1) In 'components/Controller.php'**:

```
public $metaDescription;
public $metaKeywords;

public function getMetaDescription() {
    if(!$this->metaDescription)
        return Yii::app()->settings->getValue('meta_description'); //return default description
    return $this->metaDescription;
}

public function getMetaKeywords() {
    if(!$this->metaKeywords)
        return Yii::app()->settings->getValue('meta_keywords'); //return default keywords   
    return $this->metaKeywords; 
}
```

**2) In your main.php layout**:

```
...
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag($this->getMetaDescription(), 'description');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag($this->getMetaKeywords(), 'keywords');
...
```

**3) In your other layouts**:

```
...
// If you don't do that, the description and keywords will be default for this page.
$this->metaDescription = 'Your description here';
$this->metaKeywords = 'your, keywords, here';
...
```

Note, that Yii::app()->settings->getValue('meta_description') and Yii::app()->settings->getValue('meta_keywords')  is my default values that takes from DB.